# Shell Bash declaring an array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am having some issues declaring an array in Bash.

I am trying to use `declare -A` props

But it gives me an error that states:

```
  declare -A: invalid option           
  declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value]] ...]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the array is currently 0.

I am trying to create an array that stores a key and a value.

Comment: `declare` is a bash built-in. Are you using `ksh` or `bash`?

Comment: Why are you using -A  ??

Comment: are you by any chance using MacOS?

Comment: I am trying to create an array that stores keys and values using bash v3.00.16

Answer (score 9):

Associative arrays are declared using `declare -A`. Indexed arrays are declared using `declare -a`.

If you need the former, check your version of bash `bash --version` since they were introduced in bash 4.0.